# Unable to connect / process query into MySQL Database on Wamp Server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, wamp

*disclaimer* Yes the data isn't being verified yet and yes it isn't secure, but this is a test on a local machine so I'm not worried about SQL Injection

Ok.  So I have a form the user fills out.  I start a session at the beginning of that page.  The information is posted to a second page where the user can verify the data and then click a button to submit it.  Again the session is started and the data is passed to a third page where the connection to the database is made.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconnect.php");

include("header.php");
echo "This is for a Live Sale:  title is " . $_SESSION['title'] . "<p> type is " . $type = $_SESSION['typeofsale'] . "<p> fname is " . $_SESSION['fname'] . " <p>lname is " . $lname = $_SESSION['lname'] . "<p> email is " . $email = $_SESSION['email'] . "<p> address is " . $address = $_SESSION['address'] . " <p>zip is " . $_SESSION['zip'] . " <p>city is " . $_SESSION['city'] . "<p> county is " . $_SESSION['county'] . "<p> area is " . $_SESSION['area'] . "<p> state is " . $_SESSION['state'] . "<p> directions are " . $_SESSION['directions'] . "<p> date is " . $_SESSION['livedate'] . "<p> Time is " . $_SESSION['time']; 
    if (isset($_SESSION['livedate'])){
        $title = $_SESSION['title'];
        $typeofsale = $_SESSION['typeofsale'];
        $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
        $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $address = $_SESSION['address'];
        $zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
        $city = $_SESSION['city'];
        $county = $_SESSION['county'];
        $area = $_SESSION['area'];
        $state = $_SESSION['state'];
        $directions = $_SESSION['directions'];
        $listitems = $_SESSION['listitems'];
        $date = $_SESSION['livedate'];
        $time = $_SESSION['time']; 

        fullListing($title, $typeofsale, $fname, $lname, $email, $address, $zip, $city, $county, $area, $state, $directions, $listitems, $date, $time);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['onlinedate'])){
    $title = $_SESSION['title'];
    $typeofsale = $_SESSION['typeofsale'];
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
    $city = $_SESSION['city'];
    $county = $_SESSION['county'];
    $area = $_SESSION['area'];
    $state = $_SESSION['state'];
    $listitems = $_SESSION['listitems'];
    $date = $_SESSION['livedate'];

    partialListing($title, $typeofsale, $fname, $lname, $email, $zip, $city, $county, $area, $state, $listitems, $date);
}




function fullListing($title, $typeofsale, $fname, $lname, $email, $address, $zip, $city, $county, $area, $state, $directions, $listitems, $date, $time){
global $dbc;

$insertRow = "INSERT INTO listings(title, typeofsale, fname, lname, email, address, zip, city, county, area, state, directions, listitems, date, time) VALUES ('$title', '$typeofsale', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$address', '$zip', '$city', '$county', '$area', '$state', '$directions', '$listitems', '$date', '$time')";
echo "<p>this is whats in insertRow variable " . $insertRow;
$result = $dbc->query($insertRow);
echo "<p>this is whats in insertRow variable " . $insertRow;
}


function partialListing($title, $typeofsale, $fname, $lname, $email, $zip, $city, $county, $area, $state, $listitems, $date){
global $dbc;

$insertRow = "INSERT INTO listings(title, typeofsale, fname, lname, email, zip, city, county, area, state, listitems, date) VALUES ('$title', '$typeofsale', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$zip', '$city', '$county', '$area', '$state', '$listitems', $date)";
$result = $dbc->query($insertRow);
echo "this is whats in insertRow variable " . $insertRow;
}

echo "<p><h1>Information Submitted.  Thank You!</h1>";
echo "<p>";
include('footer.php');
```

OK so I echoed out the variables to make sure they all got transferred over as a way to bug my problems. They displayed fine with all the right information in the right variable.

I am testing out the fullListing option on the page.  I echo out the contents of $insertRow before and after the query is run.  The page runs and it only shows the first output.  Here is a result for the contents of variable $insertRow.

```
INSERT INTO listings(title, typeofsale, fname, lname, email, address, zip, city, county, area, state, directions, listitems, date, time) VALUES ('This is the title', 'livesale', 'First', 'Name', 'blah@blah.com', '`123 Main St', '44355', 'City', 'crowwing', 'central', 'minnesota', 'GO down the road til you see the sign and then go somemore Big house on the right', 'Clothes baby items playstation games toys', '6/12/1965', '8:00AM')
```

When it tries to run the query it gives me the following error.

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\AreaListingPage2\salesent.php on line 52
```

Line 52 is this line:

```
$result = $dbc->query($insertRow);
```

I checked to make sure the db connect and model have the correct information in them and they do.  They have the right password and database.  I then checked to make sure the table in the database was correct and it was.  I checked to see if the fields were in the right order and matched the database fields and they did.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Are you **SURE** that you connected to the db properly and that `$dbc` is what you expected it to be? Sounds like something failed, returned a boolean false, and since you have absolutely **NO** error handling whatsoever, your code just blundered on ahead.

Comment: I double checked the name of the database so that it matches my dbconnect page.  I double checked to make sure it was looking for the right table.  I do have error checking to see if it connects to the database in my model and no error was displayed.  I double checked to make sure the tables matched names and order.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($dbc)` just before using `query()` on it, to see if it is a correct database object. It sure looks like it isn't, which would mean that the problem is in your header.php file.

Comment: Sorry, dbconnect.php file.

Comment: it shows a null value. hmmm I noticed I didnt close the php in my dbconnect.php page so I closed it but didn't make a difference.  It just seems odd that it works perfect fine for one page connecting to a database but not the next.  It must be some syntax error somewhere.

Comment: I found the problem. I was calling dbconnect.php instead of model.php(which intern calls dbconnect.php).  Thanks for the help!  Seeing that var_dump wasnt returning anything was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You just define a `global $dbc;` that it's an empty variable and doesn't handle any connection to the database, but you call the `query()` function on it. This won't work.

You should handle the connection properly, whatever driver you are using (mysqli, PDO etc..).

Comment: in contrast, here is a file which I know works because I can test the data and see it gets inserted into the database.  I use the same code for both projects.                                                   function insertIntoTable($fname, $lname, $age, $city, $state){
global $dbc;

$insertRow = "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname, age, city, state) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$city', '$state')";
$result = $dbc->query($insertRow);
}
include('header.php');